# Hide or relocate scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a sort of "Notification Center" for my website. Basically it will allow users to view some important information. However, the notification center can be too long occasionally, so I set the containing div to overflow: scroll. My issue is that when the notification center is hidden (or set to margin-left: -99%), the scrollbar shows on the 1% of the div that constitutes the trigger. Is there any way to reposition the scrollbar or hide it when the notification center is hidden? I'm using bootstrap, and the content of the notification center is wrapped in a div class="container", but when I try to set overflow: scroll on the container, it doesn't work.

Code is at https://github.com/mathmatrix828/mstudios/blob/master/index.php, lines 27-97

Live example at http://matrixstudios.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "hide" the notification center, also set the css of the container div to `overflow:hidden`, which will remove the scrollbars.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks! And then add it back again on click of the trigger div!